# Accessing run-time generated HTML with AHK script

Tags: csv, automation, autohotkey

How do you access HTML generated at run-time on AHK?

I'm trying to access the content of the drop down box after the postcode is pasted into the search box (at this website - http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/demos/address-finder/)

[image]

For 2 entries, the web page code is as follows:

```
 <div class="pca pcalist">
    <div class="pcaitem pcafirstitem pcaselected" title=
    "MK10 0AA, A C R Logistics, Standing Way, Brinklow, Milton Keynes">
        MK10 0AA, A C R Logistics, Standing Way, Brinklow, Milton Keynes
    </div>

    <div class="pcaitem pcalastitem" title=
    "MK10 0AA, Waitrose, A C R Logistics, Standing Way, Brinklow, Milton Keynes">
    MK10 0AA, Waitrose, A C R Logistics, Standing Way, Brinklow, Milton
    Keynes
    </div>
</div>
```

For 2+ entries, the web page code is as follows:

```
<div class="pca pcalist">
    <div class="pcaitem pcafirstitem pcaselected" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 1, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 1, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 2, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 2, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 3, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 3, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 4, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 4, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 5, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 5, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 6, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 6, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 7, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 7, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 8, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 8, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 9, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 9, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 10, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 10, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 11, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 11, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 12, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 12, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 13, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 13, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 14, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 14, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 15, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 15, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 16, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 16, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>


    <div class="pcaitem pcalastitem" title=
    "MK13 7NA, 17, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes">
        MK13 7NA, 17, Bleasdale, Heelands, Milton Keynes
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code so far - it only returns a list of countries when run and not the actual addresses, I suspect that it is pointing to another pcaitem class in the document...

```
;// Fileread, test, somefilename
fileread, AddressList, mk-data-000001-1.csv


IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate("http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/demos/address-finder/")
ComObjError(false)
IE.Visible := true


loop 14
{
Send {Tab down}{Tab up}
Sleep 200
}


loop, parse, AddressList, `n, `r
{
    Clipboard = %A_LoopField%
    Send, ^v


Name_Elements := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pcaitem")
loop, % Name_Elements.length
{
Addr_text := Name_Elements[A_Index-1].innertext
} 
}
```

Sample content of mk-data-000001-1.csv

```
MK1 1AS
MK1 1AX
MK1 1BA
MK1 1BB
MK1 1BE
MK1 1BG
MK1 1BH
MK1 1BJ
MK1 1BL
MK1 1BN
MK1 1BP
MK1 1BQ
MK1 1BU
MK1 1BW
MK1 1BX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your assumption was right.
I don't think it hurts to be a little bit more precise?
I used the following:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pcalist")[0].getElementsByClassName("pcaitem")
```

Here's a test example

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2

IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate("http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/demos/address-finder/")
ComObjError(false)
IE.Visible := true
MsgBox Press OK when the page has been fully loaded.
Sleep 200
WinMaximize, Internet Explorer
Sleep 1000

;click the search input field
send {PGDN}
Sleep 200
x:=A_ScreenWidth//2
Click, %x% 250
Sleep 200

;search text
Send, MK1 1AS
Sleep 200

Data:=""
ResultsList := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pcalist")[0].getElementsByClassName("pcaitem")
Loop % ResultsList.Length
    Data .= ResultsList[A_Index-1].innerHTML
StringReplace,Data,Data,</span>,`n,All
Data:=RegExReplace(Data,"<span[^<>]+>",", ")
MsgBox % Data
```

Screenshot
[image]